# How can I group all conversations (messages) in my database query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epnN.jpg

And I currently use the following query to get the list of messages for a specific loggedin user (toid)

```
SELECT 
photo,forename,surname,m.status,datetime,m.type,message,timestamp
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = m.fromid
WHERE toid = '$userID' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

then i use foreach($messages as $m):

which then echos some code that shows the messages to the user.

Currently as in the screenshot, there is messages from the same fromid and toid, and it currently prints both messages.

I am wondering is there a way to group them and only display it as one message, but showing the most recently received one?

my php loop code

```
 <?foreach ($messages as $m):?>


<li <?if ($m->status == "0"){?> class="unread" <?}?>>
<a href="dashboard-messages-conversation.html">
<div class="message-avatar"><img src="https://process.filestackapi.com/resize=width:960,height:960,fit:crop/<?echo $m->photo;?>" alt="" /></div>

<div class="message-by">
<div class="message-by-headline">
<h5><?echo $m->forename . " " . $m->surname;?> <?if ($m->status == "0"){?> <i>Unread</i><?}?></h5>
<span><? time_stamp($m->timestamp);?></span>
</div>
<p><?echo truncate($m->message, 100);?></p>
</div>
</a>
</li>



<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what contains `$m` in your foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.timestamp = (select max(m2.timestamp)
                     from messages m2
                     where (m.toid, m.fromid) in ( (m2.toid, m2.fromid), (m2.fromid, m2.toid))
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the most recent one, since you're selecting messages for a single user, you need to add the TOP clause to your select statement.

```
SELECT TOP 1
photo,forename,surname,m.status,datetime,m.type,message,timestamp
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = m.fromid
WHERE toid = '$userID' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

If you wanted the most recent message for several users, you'd probably do a self-join on messages grouped by fromid and get the fromid and max datetime to filter the messages by

```
SELECT 
photo,forename,surname,m.status,datetime,m.type,message,timestamp
FROM messages m 
inner join
(
    SELECT fromid, max(datetime) as lastmessage
    from messages
    group by fromid
) as filter ON m.fromid = filter.fromid
LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = m.fromid
ORDER BY surname, forename
```